# Ordenar notas decimais

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

Estou ordenando um json relacionado em notas em undescore.js

```
 {8.0 , 8,5 , 5,5 }

    var asc = _.sortBy(oper, function(num) {
                return num.nota;
            });
```

Soque qndo a nota da 10.0 ele não joga pra cima.. ele fica assim

```
    8.8
    6.0
    5.5
    10.0
    0.0
```

Como faco para ele entender isto?

Comment: esse json está mal formatado, o que é o `oper`? dá para clarificar?

Comment: Essas notas estão em formato string, certo? (pois `10.0` > `5.5`, mas `"10.0" < "5.5"`) De qualquer forma, não entendo por que ele está ordenando em ordem decrescente em vez de crescente, pelo código mostrado não deveria dar esse resultado, seja qual for o tipo. Poderia dar mais detalhes, por exemplo um trecho de código mais completo?

Comment: oper é o json {nota:8.0 , nota:8,5 , nota:5,5 } as notas estão em json

Comment: correto mgibsonbr! é so adcionar parseFloat() que resolvel, coloque como resposta pra eu dar como resolvido, obrigado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seu problema parece ser que as notas estão em formato string, e não numérico. A comparação de strings se dá em ordem lexicográfica, e como `"1" < "5"` então `"10.0" < "5.5"` (ainda que numericamente `10.0 > 5.5`). Convertendo os dados para número, como você mesmo percebeu, resolve o problema:

```js
var oper = [{nota:"8.8"}, {nota:"10.0"}, {nota:"6.0"}, {nota:"0.0"}, {nota:"5.5"}];

var asc = _.sortBy(oper, function(num) {
                return parseFloat(num.nota);
            });

document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(asc, null, 4) + "</pre>";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
```